# How to open PuTTY saved session with auto login?

Tags: ssh, putty

I am able to auto login to the PuTTY with my credentials by having the link to the app with -ssh credentials -pw credentials, but that is not taking into account save sessions and thus it's not using any settings saved in the saved sessions. I want to be able to auto login into saved session, if it does make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a saved sessions and still specify a password:

```
putty -load "My Session" -pw "mypw"
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved.

Comment: Keep in mind that storing passwords in plain text (including in startup scripts) is generally a bad idea.